# Giving base class access to child-class variables without getter and setter methods

Tags: c#, inheritance

The base class `MasterClass` holds a Dictionary containing a `string` key and a `HookObj` value, where `HookObj` holds (from the derived class) the variable Type, and reference to it's get/set methods.

Now when the base class `MasterClass` receives data from some source, it will cast/assign it like so:

```
//Data came in from an external source, see if we know what variable to assign the value to
public void receiveData(string key, string value)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        assignVal(dict[key], value);
    else
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //use NotImplementedException as placeholder until we make proper exception
}

//Cast the value-string to the proper type and assign it
private void assignVal(HookObj hookobj, string value)
{
    try
    {
        if (hookobj.theType == typeof(string))
            hookobj.setMethod(value);
        else if (hookobj.theType == typeof(int))
            hookobj.setMethod(Int32.Parse(value));
        else if (hookobj.theType == typeof(float))
            hookobj.setMethod(float.Parse(value));
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException ex) { throw new NotImplementedException("", ex); }
    catch (System.FormatException ex) { throw new NotImplementedException("", ex); }
}
```

With `HookObj` being:

```
internal class HookObj
{
    public Type theType { get; private set; }
    public Action<dynamic> setMethod { get; private set; }
    public Func<dynamic> getMethod { get; private set; }

    public HookObj(Type theType, Action<dynamic> setMethod, Func<dynamic> getMethod)
    {
        this.theType = theType;
        this.setMethod = setMethod;
        this.getMethod = getMethod;
    }
}
```

Use of the getter methods shouldn't need explenation. So now let's see how messy this becomes for the end user:

```
class Attachvariable : MasterClass
{
    public Attachvariable(int id) : base(id) { }
    public Attachvariable(int userID, string position)
        : base()
    {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.position = position;
    }

    int userID;
    string position;

    protected override void hookMethod()
    {
        newHookAndAdd(typeof(int), set_userID, get_userID, "userID").
        newHookAndAdd(typeof(string), set_position, get_position, "position");
    }

    public void set_userID(dynamic theVal)
    {
        userID = theVal;
    }
    public void set_position(dynamic theVal)
    {
        position = theVal;
    }

    public dynamic get_userID()
    {
        return userID;
    }
    public dynamic get_position()
    {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Where I was hoping it to be more like this:

```
protected override void hookMethod()
{
    newHookAndAdd(ref userID, "userID");
    //etc
}
```

But it's not possible to store references for later use it seems.. is there any way to make this more user friendly? Creating two functions per variable is going to get really messy I'd guess.

Comment: where is the newHookAndAdd method? I cant see it...

Comment: @furier Didn't think it was important.. I cut out alot from the MasterClass. All that method does is add to the Dictionary: `newHookAndAdd(Type theType, Action<dynamic> setMethod, Func<dynamic> getMethod, string key) { dict[key] = new HookObj(theType, setMethod, getMethod); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to @Guffa's answer, but instead of the objects holding "Hook" wrappers for the properties, I used lambdas to get/set the properties using their original value types:

**MasterClass:**

```
class MasterClass
{
    Dictionary<string, HookObj> dict = new Dictionary<string, HookObj>();

    //Data came in from an external source, see if we know what variable to assign the value to
    public void receiveData(string key, string value)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
            assignVal(dict[key], value);
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException(); //use NotImplementedException as placeholder until we make proper exception
    }

    //Cast the value-string to the proper type and assign it
    private void assignVal(HookObj hookobj, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (hookobj.theType == typeof(string))
                hookobj.SetValue(value);
            else if (hookobj.theType == typeof(int))
                hookobj.SetValue(Int32.Parse(value));
            else if (hookobj.theType == typeof(float))
                hookobj.SetValue(float.Parse(value));
            else
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException ex) { throw new NotImplementedException("", ex); }
        catch (System.FormatException ex) { throw new NotImplementedException("", ex); }
    }

    protected void newHookAndAdd<T>(Action<T> setter, Func<T> getter, string name)
    {
        HookObj hook = new HookObj<T>(setter, getter);
        dict.Add(name, hook);
    }
}
```

**HookObj**

```
public class HookObj<T> : HookObj
{
    public Action<T> setMethod { get; private set; }
    public Func<T> getMethod { get; private set; }

    public HookObj(Action<T> setMethod, Func<T> getMethod)
        : base(typeof(T))
    {
        this.setMethod = setMethod;
        this.getMethod = getMethod;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        setMethod((T)value);
    }

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return getMethod();
    }
}


public abstract class HookObj
{
    public Type theType { get; private set; }

    public HookObj(Type theType)
    {
        this.theType = theType;
    }

    public abstract void SetValue(object value);
    public abstract object GetValue();
}
```

Then your subclasses of MasterClass:

```
class Attachvariable : MasterClass
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public Attachvariable()
    {
        hookMethod();
    }

    protected void hookMethod()
    {   
        newHookAndAdd(value => UserID = value, () => UserID, "userID");
        newHookAndAdd(value => Position = value, () => Position, "position");
    }
}
```

You could even setup your hook registrants to provide a parser:

```
class YesNoVariable : MasterClass
{
    public bool YesNo { get; set; }

    public YesNoVariable()
    {
        hookMethod();
    }

    protected void hookMethod()
    {   
        newHookAndAdd(value => YesNo = value, () => YesNo, "yesno", (input) => input == "yes");
    }
}
```

I didn't go through the motions of adding the parser as an optional parameter to the base handlers, I'll leave that to you as it's trivial at this stage. Essentially your `assignValue` would check if the `HookObj` has a parser assigned and if it does, to use it. Otherwise it goes through the same motions you already have.

In fact, I would have all of the hooks use a parser and have specific `IntHookObj`, `FloatHookObj` and so on. The `newHookAndAdd` method would essentially be a factory. If the user provides their own parser, it would create a `HookObj` with that custom parser. If `T` is int/float/string it would instantiate a known `HookObj` implementation so you don't intermix all your parsing logic with the assignment process.

EDIT: I ended up throwing together an implementation using custom parsers and ditching the if/elseif/elseif type checks altogether:

**Hook base classes**

```
public abstract class HookObj<T> : HookObj
{
    public Action<T> setMethod { get; private set; }
    public Func<T> getMethod { get; private set; }


    protected HookObj()
        : base(typeof(T))
    {

    }

    public void SetSetter(Action<T> setMethod)
    {
        this.setMethod = setMethod;
    }

    public void SetGetter(Func<T> getMethod)
    {
        this.getMethod = getMethod;
    }

    protected abstract T Parse(string value);

    public override void SetValue(string value)
    {
        T parsedValue = Parse(value);
        setMethod(parsedValue);
    }

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return getMethod();
    }
}


public abstract class HookObj
{
    public Type theType { get; private set; }

    public HookObj(Type theType)
    {
        this.theType = theType;
    }

    public abstract void SetValue(string value);
    public abstract object GetValue();
}
```

**Standard Hook Implementations**

```
public class StringHook : HookObj<string>
{
    protected override string Parse(string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class IntHook : HookObj<int>
{
    protected override int Parse(string value)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(value);
    }
}

public class FloatHook : HookObj<float>
{
    protected override float Parse(string value)
    {
        return float.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

**Custom Hook Parser Handler**

```
public class CustomHook<T> : HookObj<T>
{
    public Func<string, T> inputParser { get; private set; }

    public CustomHook(Func<string, T> parser)
    {
        if (parser == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parser");

        this.inputParser = parser;
    }

    protected override T Parse(string value)
    {
        return inputParser(value);
    }
}
```

**MasterClass:**

```
class MasterClass
{
    Dictionary<string, HookObj> dict = new Dictionary<string, HookObj>();

    //Data came in from an external source, see if we know what variable to assign the value to
    public void receiveData(string key, string value)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
            assignVal(dict[key], value);
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException(); //use NotImplementedException as placeholder until we make proper exception
    }

    //Cast the value-string to the proper type and assign it
    private void assignVal(HookObj hookobj, string value)
    {
        hookobj.SetValue(value);
    }

    protected void RegisterProperty<T>(Action<T> setter, Func<T> getter, string name, Func<string, T> inputParser)
    {
        var hook = new CustomHook<T>(inputParser);
        hook.SetSetter(setter);
        hook.SetGetter(getter);
        dict.Add(name, hook);
    }

    protected void RegisterProperty(Action<string> setter, Func<string> getter, string name)
    {
        var hook = new StringHook();
        hook.SetSetter(setter);
        hook.SetGetter(getter);
        dict.Add(name, hook);
    }

    protected void RegisterProperty(Action<int> setter, Func<int> getter, string name)
    {
        var hook = new IntHook();
        hook.SetSetter(setter);
        hook.SetGetter(getter);
        dict.Add(name, hook);
    }

    protected void RegisterProperty(Action<float> setter, Func<float> getter, string name)
    {
        var hook = new FloatHook();
        hook.SetSetter(setter);
        hook.SetGetter(getter);
        dict.Add(name, hook);
    }
}
```

Now, the MasterClass could use a bit of work. Specifically, I *feel* that the `RegisterProperty` methods (which replaced newHookAndAdd) are duplicating work and you'd have to add entries for each "standard" hook type that you support. I'm sure there's a nicer way to do it, but for now it provides your "Attachvariable" subclasses to not care about what hooks are used, they **know** which types are supported natively, and its typesafe. Any types not supported natively, they *must* supply a typesafe parser.

**Attachvariable sample:**

```
class Attachvariable : MasterClass
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public bool YesNo { get; set; }
    public bool ProperBoolean { get; set; }

    public Attachvariable()
    {
        RegisterProperties();
    }

    protected void RegisterProperties()
    {   
        RegisterProperty(value => UserID = value, () => UserID, "userID");
        RegisterProperty(value => Position = value, () => Position, "position");
        RegisterProperty(value => YesNo = value, () => YesNo, "yesno", (input) => input == "yes");
        RegisterProperty(value => ProperBoolean = value, () => ProperBoolean, "ProperBoolean", (input) => Boolean.Parse(input));
    }
}
```

The `string` and `int` properties are supported natively; they hit the `RegisterProperty` overloads tied to their type. However, the `bool` types are not supported natively so they provide their own parsing logic. The "yesno" simply checks that the string equals "yes". The "ProperBoolean" performs the standard `Boolean.Parse`. Usage looks like:

```
Attachvariable obj = new Attachvariable();

obj.receiveData("userID", "9001");
obj.receiveData("position", "Hello World!");
obj.receiveData("yesno", "yes");
obj.receiveData("ProperBoolean", "True");

Console.WriteLine(obj.UserID); //9001
Console.WriteLine(obj.Position); //"Hello World!"
Console.WriteLine(obj.YesNo); //True
Console.WriteLine(obj.ProperBoolean); //True

obj.receiveData("yesno", "something else!");
Console.WriteLine(obj.YesNo); //False

obj.receiveData("ProperBoolean", "Invalid Boolean!"); //throws exception on `Boolean.Parse` step as intended
```

I thought about having the "Standard" hooks inherit from the CustomHook and just pass the parse methods down, but this way you can create new standard hooks that might have more complicated parsing logic so this should make it a bit easier to read/implement. At anyrate, I whipped this off and if I were to use it in production, I'd take more time to clean/improve/test.

A *biiiiiiiig* plus is this makes it *very easy* to unit test your individual hook type implementations. Could probably refactor the `MasterClass` to make it easier to unit test (albeit it's pretty simple now), maybe move the hook creators into a separate factory/builder.

EDIT: Heck, now just throw out the `theType` field on the `HookObj` base and replace it with an interface:

```
public interface IHookObj
{   
    void SetValue(string value);
    object GetValue();
}
```

You can propagate the changes throughout (`HookObj<T>` no longer calls a base constructor passing in `typeof(T)`, `MasterClass` is now tied to an `IHookObj` interface). This means you can even more easily define hooks that use *whatever logic they want*, parsing or otherwise, and should be even easier to test.

EDIT: Yeah, here's a sample implementation where a *third party consumer* of your API can provide their own hooks that can be reused across their application. If they had `Person` objects used everywhere, they just define a single hook and it can get reused:

```
class SomeCustomUsage : MasterClass
{
    public Person SomeoneUnimportant { get; set; }

    public SomeCustomUsage()
    {
        RegisterProperty(value => SomeoneUnimportant = value, () => SomeoneUnimportant, "SomeoneUnimportant", new PersonHook());
    }
}
```

With their `PersonHook` being:

```
public class PersonHook : HookObj<Person>
{
    protected override Person Parse(string value)
    {
        string[] parts = value.Split(',');
        var person = new Person(parts[0], parts[1]);

        if (person.FirstName == "Bob")
            throw new Exception("You have a silly name and I don't like you.");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.FirstName))
            throw new Exception("No first name provided.");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.LastName))
            throw new Exception("No last name provided.");

        return person;
    }
}
```

Providing the `HookObj<T>` overload to `RegisterProperty` also collapsed all the overloads to something simpler with less code duplication (but still it doesn't quite *feel* right yet):

```
protected void RegisterProperty<T>(Action<T> setter, Func<T> getter, string name, HookObj<T> hook)
{
    hook.SetSetter(setter);
    hook.SetGetter(getter);
    dict.Add(name, hook);
}

protected void RegisterProperty<T>(Action<T> setter, Func<T> getter, string name, Func<string, T> inputParser)
{
    var hook = new CustomHook<T>(inputParser);
    RegisterProperty(setter, getter, name, hook);
}

protected void RegisterProperty(Action<string> setter, Func<string> getter, string name)
{
    var hook = new StringHook();
    RegisterProperty(setter, getter, name, hook);
}

protected void RegisterProperty(Action<int> setter, Func<int> getter, string name)
{
    var hook = new IntHook();
    RegisterProperty(setter, getter, name, hook);
}

protected void RegisterProperty(Action<float> setter, Func<float> getter, string name)
{
    var hook = new FloatHook();
    RegisterProperty(setter, getter, name, hook);
}
```

Results might look like:

```
SomeCustomUsage customObj = new SomeCustomUsage();
customObj.receiveData("SomeoneUnimportant", "John,Doe");
Console.WriteLine(customObj.SomeoneUnimportant.LastName + ", " + customObj.SomeoneUnimportant.FirstName); //Doe, John

customObj.receiveData("SomeoneUnimportant", "Bob,Marley"); //exception: "You have a silly name and I don't like you."
customObj.receiveData("SomeoneUnimportant", ",Doe"); //exception: "No first name provided."
customObj.receiveData("SomeoneUnimportant", "John,"); //exception: "No last name provided."
```

Comment: Lambada expressions still confuse the heck out of me.. I can barely read them. I like your parser-idea though, I'm going to try that out tomorrow.. sounds like a good lesson, thanks!

Comment: @natli Definitely take time to understand them. They seriously open a tonne of doors when it comes to fluent/readable/expressive/flexible code, used with Linq, and are used more and more often. I posted a sample implementation with parsing. Notice it completely threw out the if/elseif/elseif type checks, and coders know at _compile time_ which types are supported and which they have to supply custom parsers for.

Comment: @natli Alright, I'm done all the edits/changes. I think that answer is just about monolithic enough at this point.

Comment: Just spent some time toying with your new features; it's awesome! The amount of RegisterProperty methods isn't pretty, but not a big problem. And educational answers shouldn't be called monolithic ^^ Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

You could make a generic `Hook<T>` class to hold the value, and an abstract `Hook` base class for it that holds the type so that the `MasterClass` can get the type without knowing the actual type of the hook:

```
public class MasterClass {

  private Dictionary<string, Hook> _dict;

  public Hook<T> AddHook<T>(string name, T value){
    Hook<T> hook = new Hook<T>(value);
    _dict.Add(name, hook);
    return hook;
  }

  public void receiveData(string key, string value) {
    Hook hook;
    if (_dict.TryGetValue(key, out hook)) {
      if (hook._type == typeof(string)) {
        (hook as Hook<string>).Value = value;
      } else if (hook._type == typeof(int)) {
        (hook as Hook<int>).Value = Int32.Parse(value);
      } else {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // type not found
      }
    } else {
      throw new NotImplementedException(); // name not found
    }
  }

}

public abstract class Hook {
  internal Type _type;
  internal Hook(Type type) {
    _type = type;
  }
}

public class Hook<T> : Hook {
  public T Value { get; set; }
  public Hook(T value) : base(typeof(T)){
    Value = value;
  }
}
```

Now the user can create `Hook<T>` objects to hold the values:

```
class Attachvariable : MasterClass {

  private Hook<int> userId;
  private Hook<string> position;

  private Attachvariable() : base() {
    userId = AddHook("userID", 0);
    position = AddHook("position", String.Empty);
  }

  public Attachvariable(int id, string pos) : this() {
    userId.Value = id;
    position.Value = pos;
  }

}
```

Comment: This looks awesome, going to try it out tomorrow (too late now). If it works the way I think it does it's exactly what I need ;)

Comment: But i don't understand why one would like to do all this, just because u can or what the hell? What use do you have for it? I'm just curious :)

Comment: @furier Ok I'll just copy this comment over then: The point is that the child class can add as many variables as it wants, and the base class will pick them up without having to be altered.. BaseClass doesn't know a user wants to add "int UserID" or whatever else, but baseclass must be able to work with it, still. The key here is the "receiveData" function in the BaseClass. It operates on the child class' variables. It's really not that weird :P

Comment: when you are talking about variables you are talking about fields? And you want the child class to have fields added and removed dynamically at runtime? Well a dictionary will do this for you perfectly with a key and just storing the object, maybe inside a custom object that holds its type and so forth... But either way you are either instantiating an instance of the parent class (in which it will have no information what so ever about child classes) or the child class, where the child class can access everything in the parent class that is not private.

Comment: @furier: "maybe inside a custom object that holds its type and so forth" - Yes, that's exactly how this works. And the child class gets a reference to that object, so that it doesn't have to dig in the dictionary for it and cast the value to the correct type.

Comment: @furier No I don't want to add/remove them at runtime, that wouldn't make any sense :P The BaseClass is a library with a specific purpose: receiving data by key(string)/value(string) and then assigning said value to the corresponding child class' variable (or field as you call it). The child class knows what data it wants to receive, it only needs BaseClass to actually do so, so it also doesn't have to add/remove fields at runtime.

Comment: @Guffa yeah i noticed, thats why i wrote it, but should have made it clear that i understood that from your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why all the smoke and mirrors?  What's wrong with something more straight forward like this?

**Suggestion 1**

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    private int _userId;

    protected override int UserId
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set { _userId = value; }
    }
}
```

**Suggestion 2**

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected readonly Dictionary<string, object> Values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass()
    {
        Values["UserID"] = 123;
        Values["Foo"] = "Bar";
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is that the child class can add as many variables as it wants, and the base class will pick them up without having to be altered.. BaseClass doesn't know a user wants to add "int UserID" or whatever else, but baseclass must be able to work with it, still.

Comment: Yeah that works perfectly but in your simple example the ChildClass wouldn't need one line of code, if UserID was not virtual... And since the only class i can instantiate would be the ChildClass... But i presume it was for demonstration purposes :)

Comment: Ok, how about suggestion 2 I added?  It seems that you want access from the base class, but you want arbitrary variables added - so you're not going to achieve full type safety.

Comment: Your second suggestion still doesn't tackle the problem in a way I like. It's less messy this way for the child class, but the child class doesn't have any 'real' member variables anymore.. I'll have to access them via the BaseClass dictionary and that isn't exactly user friendly either.